# c# check if the user member of a group?

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, authorization

I have a code that I use to check if the user is member of the AD, worked perfectly,

now I want to add the possibility to check if the user also a member of a group!

what do I need to modify to achieve that, I did some work, but it fails!

so here is my code:

```
        //Authenticate a User Against the Directory
        private bool Authenticate(string userName,string password, string domain)
        {

            if (userName == "" || password == "")
            {
                return false;
            }

            bool authentic = false;
            try
            {
                DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain,userName, password);
                object nativeObject = entry.NativeObject;
                authentic = true;
            }
            catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException) { }
            return authentic;
        }
```

I  want to make it like this:

```
private bool Authenticate(string userName,string password, string domain, string group)
```

Comment: You may be using the wrong API for this task. Are you writing authentication code for an application? If so, there should be a much simpler API to use. For example, in ASP.NET, you can access this information using the Page.User object. Or is the purpose of the application actually to query Active Directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solve it with this code

```
public bool AuthenticateGroup(string userName, string password, string domain, string group)
    {


        if (userName == "" || password == "")
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, userName, password);
            DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(|(cn=" + userName + ")(sAMAccountName=" + userName + ")))";
            SearchResult result = mySearcher.FindOne();

            foreach (string GroupPath in result.Properties["memberOf"])
            {
                if (GroupPath.Contains(group))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException)
        {
        }
        return false;
    }
```

it works fine for me, and it can be use with a machine not part of the Domain Controller / Active Directory

Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 29):

*This is not available on Windows XP or earlier.*

Anyway, in order to check for group membership, you can use this code:

```
bool IsInGroup(string user, string group)
{
    using (var identity = new WindowsIdentity(user))
    {
        var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
        return principal.IsInRole(group);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did used this code with different users and passwords from a machine that is not a member of the DC! and it works!

Comment: Thanks, but how to integrate this in my code? the "string user" is confusing me! also is there some doc that I can take a look at?

Comment: It's the user name in the domain. It will probably work with just the user name if the machine is in the same domain, or it may work with *user@domain* or *domain\user*.

Comment: For me this one worked like a charm and I didn't need to authenticate the requested user, at all.

Comment: Where's the problem with Windows XP? Will `new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).IsInRole(group)` work in Windows XP?

Comment: This approach requires authentication on my "local" Windows 8.1 machine. So it seems to work only in domain environments, which is stupid of MS!

Answer (score 8):

In ASP.Net you will use `Page.User.IsInRole("RoleName")` or in Windows you can use `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("RoleName")`

Comment: "RoleName" is the "Group" Name?

Comment: Yes, a user can belong to various Roles (groups).