# Application use Domain Account for security

Tags: c#, security, permissions, dns

Is there a way to implement domain authentication for a group of users in a winform application?

I am writing an application in C# that is going to be installed on a few PC's in our shop. I want to password protect a portion of the programs functions, basically the configuration. I could easily hard-code a password into the application or even make an encrypted password store but I want only certain users to be able to access the configuration form and I want to manage those users centrally from our domain using a group. So anyone belonging to the "configure" group can access the form, press an apply button, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a user is in a particular Windows group, [WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal.isinrole.aspx), such as:

```
bool IsInGroup(string user, string group)
{
    using (var identity = new WindowsIdentity(user))
    {
        var principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
        return principal.IsInRole(group);
    }
}
```

To see what the current usre is, use [Thread.CurrentPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx).

See [c# check if the user member of a group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366090/c-sharp-check-if-the-user-member-of-a-group) for more information and some discussion.

However, is this the best solution for your use case? If you are "in [your] shop", are referring to point of sales terminals where multiple users going to be using a computer? In this case, users may not want to log on or log off each time. Perhaps moving the configuration to a separate application, protect the configuration using file permissions (such as read-only to non managers) and restricting access to the configuration application is a better solution.

Comment: Its custom measurement logging and reporting application for a workstation. The user logs their name, job#, part#, etc. and then prints a report which is given back to the customer. The problem is the template for the tags needs to be changed from time to time and I don't want just anyone to make the change, only the shop foreman or engineering. So when someone clicks the settings button, the standard UAC window pops up asking for the users domain name and password which will either allow or deny them the ability to get to the settings page.

Comment: Also: The computers have a default login name that is not tied to a user, only the machine. So the account is already limited to only opening up the logging software. Anyone can sit at that machine and use the software, that was the original idea. I thought that a UAC like window popping up when the user clicked settings was a neat idea that would streamline and simplify the authentication process. So if a user needs to setup another job the foreman enters his credentials and changes the template to reflect the new job. This minimizes mistakes and clearly defines accountability.

Comment: @MisterTea Interesting use of UAC. I do not think that was how it was intended but sounds effective. I have added to the answer talking about using Threat.CurrentPrincipal to get the user the application is running as.