# How to test if AD User is a member of a local group

Tags: c#, active-directory, active-directory-group

The IT department approval process for creating new AD groups is very cumbersome, so I've been tasked with looking at ways to use local groups to control access.

On Windows Server 2008 R2 I have created a local group, and have added several other AD groups along with some AD user accounts as members.

I need to write some C# code to determine if a particular AD user belongs to a particular local group, where the local group contains a mixture of AD groups and AD users.  The AD groups may in some cases contain nested AD groups.

**Update**

The code below works when a domain user account is directly a member of a local group, but it does not work when a local group contains a domain group which the domain user is a member of.

```
public static void Test()
{
    // returns true, domain user account user623 is in domain group ...
    bool b1 = UserIsInDomainGroup("user623", "apc.app.cartopac.surfaceland");

    // returns true - user623 is directly in local.groupa
    bool b2 = UserIsInlocalGroup("user623", "local.groupa");

    // returns false, even though apc.app.cartopac.surfaceland is in local.groupb
    bool b3 = UserIsInlocalGroup("user623", "local.groupb");
}

public static bool UserIsInDomainGroup(string userName, string grpName)
{
    var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "contoso");
    var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, userName);
    return user.IsMemberOf(domainContext, IdentityType.Name, grpName);
}

public static bool UserIsInlocalGroup(string userName, string localgrpName)
{
    var machineContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);
    var grpPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(machineContext, IdentityType.Name, localgrpName);
    var domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "contoso");
    var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, userName);
    return user.IsMemberOf(grpPrincipal);
}
```

Comment: Can't use just use : `user.IsMemberOf(grpPrincipal)` ?? Does that work for you?

Comment: @marc_s I've changed the code to us IsMemberOf, but still doesn't produce expected results.

Comment: Okay. In the first post you stated, that you want to check if the user is in the group. Not if the user is in any nested groups. But that's not a problem either. Tell us what your ultimate goal is, and how the code is to be used. Just throwing code at you might not be the best...

Comment: PrincipalContext and others implements IDisposable and must be disposed. This example code breaks that contract and can leak memory (among other bad things). Add using blocks around the using objects which implement IDisposable.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample works fine ASSUMING that you are passing UserPrincipalName and not sAMAccountName to the method, and that contoso is only in the sample to obscure..

Edit:

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4366162/1027551).  It checks if the user is a member, even through group nesting:

```
bool b1 = IsInGroup("sAMAccountName", "LOCALGROUPNAME");


    static bool IsInGroup(string user, string group)
    {
      using (WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(user))
      {
        WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
        return principal.IsInRole(group);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I've updated the sample a bit. I think I'm passing a UserPrincipalName.  Does this make sense?  Thanks.